# Kinesis Confluent Connector not reaching MSK Cluster

Tags: amazon-kinesis, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I am trying to add a Kinesis connector to connect my Kinesis Stream with my AWS MSK Cluster, so that I can send messages from the Kinesis to a certain topic in the Kafka cluster.
This is the connector I am trying to add: https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-kinesis

The problem is that the creation fails, and when checking in the logs, I see this message:

```
[Worker-09c2e6449b0bd54f5] [2023-08-03 09:30:01,966] WARN [msk-kinesis-connector|worker] [AdminClient clientId=msk-kinesis-connector-license-manager] Error connecting to node <bootstrap server URL>:9098 (id: -2 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1011)

[Worker-09c2e6449b0bd54f5] java.net.UnknownHostException: <bootstrap server URL>
```

The cluster has both SASL/SCRAM and IAM enabled, so I am trying to access via IAM, with just Private Endpoint (single-VPC), it has no public endpoint.

The connector is in the same subnet and has the same security groups as the Cluster, and they allow themselves as inbound traffic, so I think that there should be no problem with connectivity.

In the connector configuration, I tried with multiple options, right now I have the following:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.kinesis.KinesisSourceConnector
producer.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=<bootstrap server URL>:9098,<bootstrap server URL>:9098,<bootstrap server URL>:9098
producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
tasks.max=1
kinesis.region=eu-central-1
consumer.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
kinesis.stream=kinesis_stream_name
confluent.license=
producer.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
confluent.topic.replication.factor=3
sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
name=msk-kinesis-connector
kafka.topic=testing
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
```

I got some of them from https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/kinesis/current/kinesis_source_connector_config.html and I think I am not missing anything related to connectivity

For the VPC ACL, I have the following:

```
10  SSH (22)    TCP (6) 22  0.0.0.0/0   Deny
11  RDP (3389)  TCP (6) 3389    0.0.0.0/0   Deny
100 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   Allow
*   All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   Deny
```

And in one of the security groups, all inbound traffic from itself is allowed, and also all outbund traffic.

I also tried to add all the msk policies to the role, just in case something was missing, but no luck:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "kafkaconnect:*",
                "kafka-cluster:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kafkaconnect:*:<accountId>:worker-configuration/*/*",
                "arn:aws:kafkaconnect:*:<accountId>:custom-plugin/*/*",
                "arn:aws:kafkaconnect:*:<accountId>:connector/*/*",
                "arn:aws:kafka:*:<accountId>:topic/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:kafka:*:<accountId>:cluster/*/*",
                "arn:aws:kafka:*:<accountId>:group/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:kafka:*:<accountId>:transactional-id/*/*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kafkaconnect:ListConnectors",
                "kafkaconnect:CreateCustomPlugin",
                "kafkaconnect:CreateConnector",
                "kafkaconnect:DeleteConnector",
                "kafkaconnect:ListCustomPlugins",
                "kafkaconnect:DeleteCustomPlugin",
                "kafkaconnect:CreateWorkerConfiguration",
                "kafkaconnect:UpdateConnector",
                "kafkaconnect:ListWorkerConfigurations"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kafka:ListClustersV2",
                "kafka:ListVpcConnections",
                "kafka:DescribeClusterOperation",
                "kafka:GetCompatibleKafkaVersions",
                "kafka:ListClusters",
                "kafka:ListKafkaVersions",
                "kafka:GetBootstrapBrokers",
                "kafka:ListConfigurations",
                "kafka:DescribeClusterOperationV2"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": "kafka:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kafka:*:<accountId>:vpc-connection/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:kafka:*:<accountId>:cluster/*/*",
                "arn:aws:kafka:*:<accountId>:configuration/*/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Any idea on why it is not reaching the MSK cluster? I thought that setting it on the same VPC with the same SG would work.